# How to change or configure directory for View razor cshtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have tried to update Razor cshtml view pages path but it's not taking.To update view pages location i have tried like
**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
    {
        EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true
    };
    services.AddMvc();//.WithRazorPagesRoot("/Home/myapp");
    //services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Home/myapp");
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
    services.AddCors(option =>
    {
        option.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", policy => policy.WithOrigins("*"));
        option.AddPolicy("AllowGetMethod", policy => policy.WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Current view pages path

```
Views/Home/Index.cshtml
  Views/Home/AppHome.cshtml
```

Want to modify Views path something like this

```
Views/Home/myapp/Index.cshtml
 Views/Home/myapp/AppHome.cshtml
```

But not after service configuration it's not working.How to change View pages directory?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use feature folders, this will allow you to customize the view location: https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders

Answer (score 1):

> **ASP.NET Framework**

To change the view search locations it is necessary to create a new class derived from `RazorViewEngine` and change the values for one or more of the following properties:

- ViewLocationFormats
- MasterLocationFormats
- PartialViewLocationFormats

Each of these properties is an array of strings, which are expressed using the composite string formatting notation. For the `ViewLocationFormats` property the default values are:

```
~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml,
~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml,
~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml,
~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml
```

The following are the parameter values that correspond to the placeholders:

- {0} represents the name of the view.
- {1} represents the name of the controller.

The following example shows how to change the view locations required above:

```
public class CustomLocationViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomLocationViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
        {                
            "~/Views/{1}/myapp/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

The next step is to register `CustomLocationViewEngine` by using the `ViewEngines.Engines` collection in the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    for (var i = ViewEngines.Engines.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (ViewEngines.Engines[i] is System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine)
        {            
            // Remove the current Razor view engine
            ViewEngines.Engines.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }    
    // Add the new customized view engine
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomLocationViewEngine());

    //…
}
```

> **ASP.NET CORE 3.1**

For MVC Core 3.1 the `ConfigureServices` method in *Startup.cs* should be updated as below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{1}/myapp/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/myapp/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
     });
}
```

For additional information see [RazorViewEngineOptions.ViewLocationFormats Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.viewlocationformats?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_RazorViewEngineOptions_ViewLocationFormats)

Comment: I have Stateless ASP.NET core app running on .NET
Framework.(Web api MVC)...there is no `.asax` file in project...can i use use in `startup.cs` file?

Comment: @r08 - For the ASP.NET MVC CORE 3.1 version the update looks different. See fixes above.